# what are standard ways to write json(coming from front end) data to models.py in Django

Tags: python, json, django, dictionary

In my Django application, I need to write JSon coming from front end into tables in models.py. The first step to do this, would be convert that Json to dictionary. My question is how to write that dictionary directly to models.py tables? What if some of the fields should be written to one table and some fields should be written to any other table? Is it possible or there is another solution for this? Kindly suggest solutions.

## example

There are two tables in models.py called as chart and columnChart , chart_name and chart_description should be written to chart table whereas x_axis_mapping and y_axis_mapping should be written to columnChart table.
All the fields are received in one object called json_data.
json_data can be converted to dictionary. So what is the next step?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post models.py, views.py and forms.py?

Comment: More information would be helpful.
Is this like an import command? Or should the data be validated?
If the latter, than use a Form to validate and return an object

Comment: Whatever it is .. just extract the json and standard way to `.save()` will work..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to write directly a dictionary into a Model's table is using python's expansion with django ORM

Ex:

```
myitems = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3'}
mymodel = MyModel(**myitems)
mymodel.save()
```

For multiple models/tables you can easily filter dictionary and then use it in specific model/table.

Ex:

```
myitems1 = dict((k,myitems[k]) for k in ('key1',) if k in myitems)
mymodel1 = MyModel1(**myitems1)
mymodel1.save()
myitems2 = dict((k,myitems[k]) for k in ('key2', 'key3') if k in myitems)
mymodel2 = MyModel2(**myitems2)
mymodel2.save()
```

Comment: thanks.. I'll try this..Is this alternative to create() method?  Is there any way to take out some fields from myitems and write into mymodel? for instance key1:value1 to mymodel1 and remaining fields to mymodel2? Can you elaborate more?

Comment: @PallaviKulkarni little difference between save() and create() methods are documented in [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.create)

Comment: I added in my answer an example for multiple models.

Comment: @PallaviKulkarni if it works for you can you accept my answer?

Comment: @PallaviKulkarni can I ask you if my answer works to solve your question ?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest looking into http://www.django-rest-framework.org/

The framework handles serializing, deserializing, and dealing with various input types as well as building RESTful API's. The serializers also follow Django's DRY philosophy.